# Validation error on date field even though submitted date is valid, and no validation rules are set

Tags: webforms

I'm having a strange problem with a date field on a webform.

I have it set, in the Element Settings, to a minimum date of "today" and a maximum date of +2 months. To my understanding, this should allow the viewer to select any date from the day they are submitting the form to two months later. Under Form Validation, nothing is checked — so to my understanding, it should not be performing any sort of validation.

But — when I test the form, no matter what value I set for the date, I get "The value in (the name of the webform): Date has to be greater than Thu, 12/17/2020 - 00:00." Even though the value IS greater than that. Even dates weeks in the future result in the same message.

I initially got a similar error for the time field that follows it, but that one disappeared when I switched the element from jQuery time picker to HTML5 time input. (I had initially used the jQuery time picker for both, but switched it to HTML5 because the jQuery picker was giving me other weird problems). But switching to HTML5 did not affect the validation issue with the date field.

So basically I have two questions: First, since I didn't set any rules under Form Validation, why is it trying to validate input anyway? The only date min/max I set was under Element Settings, which as far as I know should only affect what's displayed to the viewer.

Second, why is the unwanted validation insisting that the date has to be greater than today when the date IS greater than today?

I should add: Clientside Validation is installed, so the message is appearing as soon as I leave the field in question. But to my knowledge that just takes the validation errors Webform generates and displays them sooner, it doesn't create new ones. Although the error only seems to be appearing inline on the form — it doesn't give me an error message when I submit.

Comment: Which version of Webform are you using?

Comment: Webform 8.x-5.22. Also, Clientside Validation 8.x-2.0-rc1, and Drupal itself is v. 8.9.11.

Comment: If you suspect Client Validation may be the issue, export your config, uninstall the Client Validation module, and then see if you can reproduce the error with Webform.  It's always better to try to reproduce the error with the minimum number of modules necessary; that way you can be more confident that you have identified the correct module behind the issue.